# How to save and edit multiple value using checkbox

Tags: symfony, checkbox

I am working in Symfony2 and I have a Form where I show checkboxes which came out of a Database. I want to save the selected checkboxes in the Database (mayby as a array or string like value1, value2). How can I handle this

This is my Code:

**Entity:**

```
 /**
 * @var string
 */
private $relevantewaben;

/**
 * @return string
 */
public function getRelevantewaben()
{
    return $this->relevantewaben;
}

/**
 * @param string $relevantewaben
 */
public function setRelevantewaben($relevantewaben)
{
    $this->relevantewaben = $relevantewaben;
}
```

**Controller:**

```
 public function newAction()
{
    $entity = new ChangeRequest();
    $form   = $this->createCreateForm($entity);

    return $this->render('OtlgCmdbBundle:ChangeRequest:new.html.twig', array(
        'entity' => $entity,
        'form'   => $form->createView(),
    ));
}


public function updateAction(Request $request, $id)
{
    $em = $this->getDoctrine()->getManager();

    $entity = $em->getRepository('OtlgCmdbBundle:ChangeRequest')->find($id);

    if (!$entity) {
        throw $this->createNotFoundException('Unable to find ChangeRequest entity.');
    }

    $deleteForm = $this->createDeleteForm($id);
    $editForm = $this->createEditForm($entity);
    $editForm->handleRequest($request);

    if ($editForm->isValid()) {
        $em->flush();

        return $this->redirect($this->generateUrl('changerequest_edit', array('id' => $id)));
    }

    return $this->render('OtlgCmdbBundle:ChangeRequest:edit.html.twig', array(
        'entity'      => $entity,
        'edit_form'   => $editForm->createView(),
        'delete_form' => $deleteForm->createView(),
    ));
}
```

Form:

```
->add('relevantewaben', 'entity', array(
             'class'    => 'OtlgCmdbBundle:applicant',
             'label'    => 'Benötigte, relevante Waben zur Umsetzung',
             'property' => 'name',
             'expanded' => true,
             'required' => false,
             'multiple' => true,
             'attr' => array('class' => 'css-checkbox')
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you declare the relationship between you entity and OtlgCmdbBundle:applicant, where your entity is the owner side of the relationship, Doctrine will take your changes in account automatically. For example, instead of

```
/**
 * @var string
 */
private $relevantewaben;
```

you should have sth like

```
/**
 * @var \Doctrine\Common\Collections\ArrayCollection
 * @ORM\OneToMany(targetEntity="applicant", mappedBy="changeRequests", cascade={"persist"})
 */
 private $relevantewaben;
```

Take a look at : http://docs.doctrine-project.org/en/2.0.x/reference/association-mapping.html

If what you want to save is not the relationship but, in fact, the checkboxes selected themselves:

In your controller, the variable `$entity` has all your changes when you enter `if ($editForm->isValid()) {`, so you could do `$entity->getRelevantewaben()` to get which ones where selected.

When you have a field that's not mapped, you can access that data with `$form->get('relevantewaben')->getData()`, and that's the value that you have in the form field. I haven't use it to get values that were already mapped, but that can give you an idea if that's your case.

Comment: Thank you in my case, the best solution is to set up a relationship between the tables.